# Missing resource

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy,

im trying to install UWSim but when I type rosdep install UWSim it shows me this:

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource UWSim

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share

ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

I have checked and there is folder opt and every subfolders in it.
I have downloaded from wiki a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and ROS Groovy Galapagos pre-installed and tried with that and I still get this error.

Can someone help please...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57801/missing-resource/) by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow [this](http://ros.org/wiki/UWSim) for installing instructions. Assumming you have downloaded and added to your workspace the package "underwater_simulator" the command

> rosdep install UWSim

should install the required dependencies. The error is "Missing resource UWSim", which means that ROS cannot find UWSim. Test if you can do a "roscd UWSim". If you cannot, then you have to add UWSim to your workspace.

To add this package to your workspace, follow [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment). I recommend you to follow all the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on 2013-03-12**:
there is folder "underwater_simulation" in my home directory and it has subfolder "UWSim". "opt" folder with his subfolder "ros" is in File System. I tried to copy "underwater_simulation" to "ros" but it doesnt  let me.
edit:

**Comment by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on 2013-03-12**:
ros must be installed i have checked in Software Center -> Meta package for desktop-full variant of ROS.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep doesn't work this way. rosdep installs dependencies for an installed package, not the package itself.

You are going to have to find the package yourself.

Usually, when release it is available as an ubuntu package via apt-get or when somehow indexed roslocate info might find it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2